# How to update part of the encrypted data with newly encrypted data?

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes

I need to encrypt an audio file while it is being generated. I am encrypting header with dummy data(because I don't know the actual size of audio data) at the starting and encrypting the audio data on the fly. My plan is to update the header at the end with actual data size of audio file.

But, When I tried to overwrite the encrypted header data with newly encrypted header data of same size by using same key and IV and try to decrypt later, I am getting junk data generated.

Why is this happening even though I am using same key and IV? In the below code I tried to simulate what I am doing. Encrypted file of size 64 bytes generated and decrypted file of size 50 bytes generated.

Without updation: abcdabcdab0123456789012345678901234567890123456789

With header updation: ABCDABCDAB÷‹þ@óMCKL­ZƒÖ^Ô234567890123456789

Expected output: ABCDABCDAB0123456789012345678901234567890123456789

Is this the right approach to achieve partial update of already encrypted data?

```
protected void Encrypt()
{

    byte[] numBytes = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9', '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9', '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
    byte[] smallCase = {'a','b','c','d','a','b','c','d','a','b','c','d','a','b','c','d'};
    byte[] capitalCase = {'A','B','C','D','A','B','C','D','A','B','C','D','A','B','C','D'};

    try {
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2withHmacSHA1And8BIT");
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec("junglebook".toCharArray(), "Salt".getBytes(), 65536, 256);
        SecretKey tmp = null;
        tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

        /* Encryption cipher initialization. */
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);

        AlgorithmParameters params = cipher.getParameters();
        byte[] iv = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();

        Log.d("Encryption" + "iv data :", iv.toString());

        /*Open two Cipher ouput streams to the same encrypted file*/
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/Notes/sample.encrypted");
        CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(os,cipher);

        FileOutputStream os1 = new FileOutputStream(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/Notes/sample.encrypted");
        CipherOutputStream cos1 = new CipherOutputStream(os1,cipher);

        int offset = 0;
        Log.d("Encryption", "Writing cipher text to output file");
        //Write 16 bytes header data with smallCase array
        cos.write(smallCase, offset, 16);
        // write 40 bytes actual data
        cos.write(numBytes, offset, 40);

        FileOutputStream ivStream = new FileOutputStream(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/Notes/iv.dat");
        if (ivStream != null) {
            Log.d("Encryption", "Writing iv data to output file");
            ivStream.write(iv);
        }
        cos.close();

        // Overwrite header data with capitalCase array data
        cos1.write(capitalCase, offset, 16);
        cos1.close();

        ivStream.close();

    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

protected void Decrypt()
{
    byte[] dBytes = new byte[200];

    try {

        Log.d("Decryption", "Reading iv data ");
        File f1 = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath()+"/Notes/iv.dat");
        byte[] newivtext = new byte[(int)f1.length()];
        FileInputStream readivStream = new FileInputStream(sdCard.getAbsolutePath()+"/Notes/iv.dat");
        if(readivStream != null) {
            readivStream.read(newivtext);
        }

        // Generate the secret key from same password and salt used in encryption
        SecretKeyFactory dfactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2withHmacSHA1And8BIT");
        KeySpec dspec = new PBEKeySpec("junglebook".toCharArray(), "Salt".getBytes(), 65536, 256);
        SecretKey dtmp = dfactory.generateSecret(dspec);
        SecretKey dsecret = new SecretKeySpec(dtmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

        // Initialize dcipher
        Cipher dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, dsecret, new IvParameterSpec(newivtext));

        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(sdCard.getAbsolutePath()+"/Notes/sample.encrypted");
        CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(inputStream,dcipher);
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/Notes/sample.decrypted");

        int b = cis.read(dBytes);
        while(b != -1) {
            Log.d("Decryption","Bytes decrypted" + b);
            os.write(dBytes, 0, b);
            b = cis.read(dBytes);
        }
        cis.close();
        os.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using [CBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_.28CBC.29). If you look at the wikipedia page, you will note that each block depends on the previous block. If you update a block, you need to reencrypt every subsequent block.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Phylogenesis. What mode suits for these kind of situations? Any suggestions? BTW, I tried GCM mode with NOPADDING. But, I ended up with AEADBadTagException.

Comment: maybe you could use CTR mode and then you will need to update only a single block

Comment: @gusto2 Thanks for the reply. I tried CTR mode with PKCS5Padding. This time I am getting different result like ABCDABCDAB♠♠♠♠♠♠6789012345678901234567890123456789. The extra 6 bytes seems to be padded bytes. I am not clear why these extra bytes are generated. These padded bytes overwriting the actual data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you update several things:

1. you are opening multiple outputstreams to the SAME file, which is very strange, the runtime should not allow you to do that. So - write only with a single output if you want any predictable results.
2. You may read about the mode of operations see the [CRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_.28CTR.29) mode uses no padding and allows you to update only a portion of the ciphertext (assuming you use no authenticated encryption). So `AES/CTR/NoPadding` could solve your problem. (and there should be no extra bytes if you do it correctly)
3. you can update a portion of the file using the [RandomAccessFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) and overwrite portion of the ciphertext what is needed.

Comment: Thanks ... AES/CRT/NoPadding is not generating extra bytes. I am able to decrypt properly now.

Comment: I want to write the updated header at the starting of file by overwriting dummy header. So, I used multiple outputstreams. It actually worked. but, may not be right practice. If I use single CipherOutputStream, I  couldn't update at the starting of file. It's not possible to use CipherOutputStream with RandomAccessFile. From your comment you want me to generate encrypted bytes using doFinal and overwrite the header using RandomAccessFile. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: @HithendraNath indeed, that's the idea. Overwrite the file content with the encrypted byte array. Note - for the file beginning it should be ok. When you want to overwrite other portion of the file, it may be trickier

Comment: I understand. I am still not clear why GCM with NOPADDING is failed. From the list of modes provided, I understood that GCM is the best to use. using CTR mode will provide enough security?

Comment: CTR provides enough security what concerns confidentiality, but no integrity. GCM mode provides built-in integrity, so if you overwrite portion of the ciphertext, decryption fails, With other modes (CTR, CBC, OFC, ..) you should provide integrity on your own (e.g. computing HMAC of the ciphertext)

Comment: So, Whenever there is a requirement of modifying the cipher data using CTR mode is the best practice. or there any methods to achieve the same?

Comment: CTR mode enables modifying ciphertext without needing to reencrypt the rest of data. It is very effective e.g. for disk encryption. The problem is - how do you prevent malitious modifications? (search  `authenticated encryption`). That's up to you, but common practice is having some auth tag (e.g. HMAC of the ciphertext). That needs to be recomputed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable time and suggestions.

Comment: In this example I used one IV. But, I am getting an error "IV already used" while re-encrypting the updated header? Any help would be great?

Comment: How can we use multiple IVs in this scenario?

Comment: @HithendraNath you've changed the code but we have no idea what/where do you get the exception.. and - why would you use multiple IV?

Comment: Your suggestions regarding this question are working fine. But, when I tried to implement the same on Android (Key generation using AndroidKeyStore provider) I am facing issue. That's why I am getting doubt like multiple IVs needed to achieve this. I did that experiment here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47917005/data-decryption-in-case-of-modified-cipher-data  In case multiple IVs needed, how to achieve my goal of updating header was my concern? because, I am overwriting the first IV.