# Data decryption in case of modified cipher data

Tags: android, encryption, cryptography, aes

In this example, I am trying to encrypt audio file header and data using CipherOutputStream. I stored the corresponding IV1 to file.
Later, I encrypted the updated header and overwrote the previous cipher data. I stored the corresponding IV2 to file.

I feel the IV1 written to file will no longer useful, because I overwritten the first header cipher data.

On decryption side, by using IV2 I am able to decrypt updated header part only.
I am unable to decrypt the actual data even though I used IV1. It makes sense also. Because, the data that is encrypted using IV1 has been overwritten.

How can I decrypt the data in this scenario? Or am I going completely wrong? Please help?

```
protected void EncryptAndroid()
{
    byte[] data = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
            '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
            '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',                
            };
    byte[] header = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd',
            'a', 'b', 'c', 'd',};
    byte[] updatedHeader = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D',
            'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'};

    try {
        SecretKey secret = generateKeyAndroid();

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);

        AlgorithmParameters params = cipher.getParameters();
        byte[] iv = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();

        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/Notes/sample.encrypted");
        CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(os, cipher);

        int offset = 0;
        cos.write(header, offset, 10);
        cos.write(data, offset, 40);

        FileOutputStream ivStream = new FileOutputStream(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/Notes/iv.dat");
        if (ivStream != null) {
            Log.d("Encryption", "Writing iv data to output file");
            ivStream.write(iv);
        }
        ivStream.close();
        cos.close();

        //Create new instance of cipher
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);

        AlgorithmParameters params1 = cipher.getParameters();
        byte[] iv1 = params1.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();

        //Re open the file to Update the header at starting of the file.
        FileOutputStream os1 = new FileOutputStream(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/Notes/sample.encrypted");
        CipherOutputStream cos1 = new CipherOutputStream(os1, cipher);
        cos1.write(updatedHeader, offset, 10);
        cos1.close();

        FileOutputStream ivStream1 = new FileOutputStream(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/Notes/iv1.dat");
        if (ivStream1 != null) {
            Log.d("Encryption", "Writing iv data to output file");
            ivStream1.write(iv1);
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
protected void DecryptAndroid() {
    byte[] hBytes = new byte[10];
    byte[] dBytes = new byte[100];

    try {
        Log.d("Decryption", "Reading iv data ");
        File f1 = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/Notes/iv.dat");
        byte[] newivtext = new byte[(int) f1.length()];
        FileInputStream readivStream = new FileInputStream(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/Notes/iv.dat");
        if (readivStream != null) {
            readivStream.read(newivtext);
        }

        File f2 = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/Notes/iv1.dat");
        byte[] newivtext1 = new byte[(int) f2.length()];
        FileInputStream readivStream1 = new FileInputStream(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/Notes/iv1.dat");
        if (readivStream1 != null) {
            readivStream1.read(newivtext1);
        }

        // The key can also be obtained from the Android Keystore any time as follows:
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
        keyStore.load(null);
        SecretKey dsecret = (SecretKey) keyStore.getKey("key2", null);

        // Initialize dcipher
        Cipher dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding");
        dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, dsecret,new IvParameterSpec(newivtext1));

        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/Notes/sample.encrypted");
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/Notes/sample.decrypted");

        //decrypt header
        int b = inputStream.read(hBytes);
        byte[] dB = new byte[10];
        dB = dcipher.doFinal(hBytes);
        os.write(dB, 0, b);

        // Re-Initialize dcipher
        dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding");
        dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, dsecret,new IvParameterSpec(newivtext));
        FileInputStream inputStream1 = new FileInputStream(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/Notes/sample.encrypted");
        inputStream1.skip(10);
        CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(inputStream1, dcipher);
        b = cis.read(dBytes);
        while (b != -1) {
            Log.d("Decryption", "Bytes decrypted" + b);
            os.write(dBytes, 0, b);
        }
        cis.close();
        os.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you modify the encrypted header? You also need some kind of a Mac on your data, you should probably just use AES-GCM.

Comment: @James Because, I will be getting the actual header data in the last. So, first I am encrypting dummy header and actual data. After that I will encrypt the actual header and overwrite the encrypted dummy header. I will take care of integrity after that.

Comment: The simplest way of handling an IV is to just prefix the encrypted data with the IV, the IV does not need to be secret. That way the IV is part of the encrypted data it was used to create and ready to be used for decryption.

Comment: @zaph Correct. But, here I am overwriting the encrypted data created using IV1. I want to encrypt the new data using IV2 and overwrite the data that was created using IV1. Effectively I could decrypt data corresponding to IV2 only. How to handle this situation?

Comment: @zaph That works in the case where IVs and the corresponding encrypted data are different. But, in my case I need to encrypt new data using IV2 & overwrite the data encrypted using IV1. I am loosing the encrypted data corresponding to IV1. I am unable to decrypt the data because of this. How to handle this situation?

Comment: As written in [another question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47512224/how-to-update-part-of-the-encrypted-data-with-newly-encrypted-data/47528569) you can use RadomAccessFile to update part of a file (it won't work with streams, maybe with FileChannel which is "SeekableChannel"). IMHO there's really no reason using multiple IVs. And loosing IV will really prevent decrypting data. (there is really no way)

Comment: I tried opening the file as RandomAccessFile to update the new header. The issue is when I tried to encrypt(using doFilnal) the new header with the same cipher object, I am getting the exception.

Comment: I modified my question here: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/54125/data-encryption-using-aes-ctr-using-androidkeystore-provider